# Alternatively copy/assign a subset of a dataframe to multiple locations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a datafame, say `df1`, with multiple columns, one of which containing a time series. For the sake of the example, I fill the `df1` with arbitrary values (except for the dates).

```
index  A    B   C  D
0      2    3   4  2018-01-01 00:00:00
1      5    6   7  2018-01-01 00:10:00
2      8    9  10  2018-01-01 00:20:00
3      11  12  13  2018-01-01 00:30:00
4      14  15  16  2018-01-01 00:40:00
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
52559  20  21  22 2018-12-31 23:50:00
[52560 rows x 4 columns]
```

I want to select two typical weeks (hence multiple rows), say the first two weeks `w1` and `w2`

```
w1
0      2    3   4  2018-01-01 00:00:00
1      5    6   7  2018-01-01 00:10:00
2      8    9  10  2018-01-01 00:20:00
3      11  12  13  2018-01-01 00:30:00
4      14  15  16  2018-01-01 00:40:00
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
167    17  18  19  2018-01-07 23:50:00

w2
168    4    6   8  2018-01-08 00:00:00
169    10  12  14  2018-01-08 00:10:00
170    16  18  20  2018-01-08 00:20:00
171    22  24  26  2018-01-08 00:30:00
172    28  30  32  2018-01-08 00:40:00
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
336    34  36  38  2018-01-14 23:50:00
```

and copy/assign them alternatively to another dataframe `df2`, so that `df2` will be an `w1/w2/w1/w2`... with a total of 52 weeks:

```
index  A    B   C  D
0      2    3   4  2018-01-01 00:00:00
1      5    6   7  2018-01-01 00:10:00
2      8    9  10  2018-01-01 00:20:00
3      11  12  13  2018-01-01 00:30:00
4      14  15  16  2018-01-01 00:40:00
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
167    34  36  38  2018-01-14 23:50:00
168    4    6   8  2018-01-08 00:00:00
169    10  12  14  2018-01-08 00:10:00
170    16  18  20  2018-01-08 00:20:00
171    22  24  26  2018-01-08 00:30:00
172    28  30  32  2018-01-08 00:40:00
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
336    34  36  38  2018-01-14 23:50:00
0      2    3   4  2018-01-01 00:00:00
1      5    6   7  2018-01-01 00:10:00
2      8    9  10  2018-01-01 00:20:00
3      11  12  13  2018-01-01 00:30:00
4      14  15  16  2018-01-01 00:40:00
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
167    34  36  38  2018-01-14 23:50:00
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
.      .    .  .         .
[52560 rows x 4 columns]
```

There is one week during the year that will be different.

So far, I thought about looping over the entire dataframe `df1` and handle this problem with some conditions (by checking the date of each row). However, I would like to find a better/faster way.

I could also stack one week, then the other, again through a loop, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share the sample dataframe, and desired output.

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question accordingly

Comment: Are you searching for something like clever use of [iloc/loc](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/)? For example ```w1 = df.loc[2018-01-01 00:00:00:2018-01-14 23:50:00]```. You can change date in a variable which is dependent on a condition.

Comment: Yes, I am. I thought about some conditions such as `df["D"].dt.week % 2 == 1)` and  `df["D"].dt.week % 2 ==  0)` to get the indices associated with every other week. But I cannot figure out how I can change the dataframe rows whose index is contained in `df["D"].dt.week % 2 == 1)` with  the entire week `w1` (i.e., multiple rows)?